# Python Selenium: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I was working and I got a Firefox Update notification. I updated and since then it's showing a blank Firefox. On quitting it Python gives error:

```
The browser appears to have exited before we could connect
```

Comment: you can use Firefox version<=46.0  https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0/

Comment: Most probably this is coming because of firefox version and selenium version mismatch. which version of selenium & firefox you are using